# Select most the recent event date for a specific event type from a related table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables, Case and CaseEvents.

The events are basically a user updating a case and there are lots of different types of event.

I have a KPI that **two** of those events (which are different types) have to have happened within 3 minutes - the *Response Time*.

Response Time is calculated by subtracting the date in EventTypeRef 1 from the date in EventTypeRef 2 **OR** EventTypeRef 3.

I include my desired result in the table below.

Apologies if this is simple, I'm a right newbie and couldn't find anything online that was similar (though maybe I was using the wrong terminology in my searches). Thanks for your help.

I am using SQL Server 2005

---

```
'Case table'
----------

CaseRef  | CaseNo  
   1     |  1001
   2     |  1002


CaseEvents table
----------------

 CaseRef |          EventType            |     EventStartDate    | EventTypeRef
    1    |        'LTE Detected'         |  01/11/2013 09:05:36  |       1
    1    |       'Ambulance called'      |  01/11/2013 09:06:27  |       2
    2    |       'LTE Detected'          |  02/11/2013 09:11:22  |       1
    2    | 'Patient will call ambulance' |  02/11/2013 09:13:01  |       3
    1    |        'Case updated'         |  01/11/2013 09:09:34  |       4
    1    |     'Case marked complete'    |  01/11/2013 09:13:34  |       5


Desired result
--------------

CaseNo    |     LTEDetected      |      'LTE Acted On'   | 'Response time' |
   1      | 01/11/2013 09:05:36  |  01/11/2013 09:06:27  |     00:00:51    |  
   2      | 02/11/2013 09:11:22  |  02/11/2013 09:13:01  |     00:01:39    |
```

Comment: What DBMS and version are you using?

Comment: @GarethD SQLServer 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `CASE` statement within an aggregate, so you are only checking the event types you are interested in.

```
SELECT  c.CaseNo,
        LTEDetected = MIN(CASE WHEN ce.EventTypeRef = 1 THEN ce.EventStartDate END),
        LTEActedOn = MIN(CASE WHEN ce.EventTypeRef IN (2, 3) THEN ce.EventStartDate END),
        Responsetime = DATEDIFF(SECOND, 
                                MIN(CASE WHEN ce.EventTypeRef = 1 THEN ce.EventStartDate END), 
                                MIN(CASE WHEN ce.EventTypeRef IN (2, 3) THEN ce.EventStartDate END)
                            )
FROM    Case c
        INNER JOIN CaseEvents ce
            ON c.CaseRef = ce.CaseRef
GROUP BY c.CaseNo;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57fc8/1)**

Comment: Thanks @GarethD - will let you know how I get on :)

Comment: No luck, tried really hard to get it working. Returned CaseNo and occasionally LTEActedOn, but none of the others. Am sure it'll be my error though, but appreciate your effort.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't be working, I have added an example on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I think in my simplification of the tables, I may have left out something fundamental to the query working. If I give you all the details, could you have another look, if you don't mind?

Comment: No problem at all, although I probably won't have a change to look until tomorrow. You may get a better response by asking a new question will the new details on.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  CaseRef
,       datediff(second, StartDt, EndDt) as ResponseTime
from    (
        select  CaseRef
        ,       max(case when EventTypeRef = 1 then EventStartDate end) as StartDt
        ,       min(case when EventTypeRef in (2,3) then EventStartDate end) as EndDt
        from    CaseEvents
        group by
                CaseRef
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I'll give it a go now :)